# How to append to screen buffer file?

Tags: linux, gnu-screen, buffer

If I have multiple log files open in several screens and I want to copy all useful traces to a single file, I initially copy them to the screen scrollback buffer file.

Doing ">" after selecting text will overwrite the buffer.  How do I append selected text to the buffer file?

This question concerns screen commands in Linux.

Comment: Just as an added note: If this is about some specific program (*screen* or *display* could be pretty much anything; I assumed a console/terminal), then you should expand your question to make it more clear.

Answer (score 1):

Basically you've got four related operators to redirect input/output:

- `>` will redirect your output and remove existing content (if possible). For example, this will overwrite existing contents of a file, but it won't clear the console contents:

  ```
  command > mylog.log
  ```
- `>>` will append your output to existing content, *which is most likely the behavior you're looking for:*

  ```
  command >> mylog.log
  ```
- `<` will read some source and treat it as input (`stdin`):

  ```
  command < readfile.txt
  ```
- `|` will redirect output to the input of the following command:

  ```
  command | othercommand
  ```